# Knockout foreach not working

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I have the following HTML:

```
<!-- ko.foreach: properties -->
<span data-bind="text: $data.Name"></span>
<span data-bind="text: $data.Age"></span>
<!-- /ko -->
```

And this javascript:

```
function MyViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.properties = ko.observableArray([
        {Name: "John", Age: 32},
        {Name: "Steve", Age: 23}
    ]);
}
ko.applyBindings(new MyViewModel());
```

Here's the jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/cFB5B/

Why doesn't the foreach work?

Comment: what about including the lib into the fiddle?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's `ko foreach`, not `ko.foreach` when binding a [foreach inside a HTML comment (Note 4)](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html):

```
<!-- ko foreach: properties -->
<span data-bind="text: Name"></span>
<span data-bind="text: Age"></span>
<!-- /ko -->
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cFB5B/1/

Also, you don't need to use the $data, but that wasn't causing the problem.

Answer (score 4):

You have a type `.` to much in the `foreach` declaration:

Instead

```
<!-- ko.foreach: properties -->
```

it should be

```
<!-- ko foreach: properties -->
```